# Kubernetes - how to tear down cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I've been trying to shut down kubernetes cluster , but I couldn't managed to do it.

When I type

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

I can see that my cluster is still running.

I tried commands like running script

```
kube-down.sh
```

but it didn't work.

I deleted all pods. How can I shut it down ?

Comment: This depends on how you created the cluster. It isn't possible to manage the cluster infrastructure via kubectl. You have to provide more information.

Comment: kube-down.sh will work on a cluster brought up using kube-up. I second what the comment above said. This needs further detail.

Answer (score 18):

The tear down section of the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#tear-down) says:

> To undo what kubeadm did, you should first drain the node and make sure that the node is empty before shutting it down.
>
> Talking to the master with the appropriate credentials, run:

```
kubectl drain <node name> --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets 
kubectl delete node <node name>
```

> Then, on the node being removed, reset all kubeadm installed state:

```
kubeadm reset
```

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use `kubectl stop` command as it has been deprecated. If you have created pods using a yaml file, I suggest you use 
`kubectl delete -f <filename>.yml` to stop any running pod.

You can also delete service associated with running pods by using the following command:

```
# Delete pods and services with same names "baz" and "foo"
kubectl delete pod,service baz foo
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `kube-down.sh` you've to make sure that all the environment variables which were adjusted for the `kube-up.sh` are also used during the shut down. [See also](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/#tearing-down-the-cluster)